# (SQL Oracle) How can I join 3 tables for hotel reservation system?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables in my Oracle DB for hotel website project.

1. Table Room
   a. room_num
   b. capacity (how many guests are staying)
2. Table Reservation (for members)
   a. room_num
   b. checkin_date
   c. checkout_date
3. Table Reservation2 (for non-members)
   a. room_num
   b. checkin_date
   c. checkout_date

I want to write a query that returns the list of rooms that are:

1. Bigger than or equal to the capacity X
2. Available within the checkin_date Y and the checkout_date Z

I was able to find the available rooms when I worked with only two tables, `ROOM` and `RESERVATION`.
But I'm having trouble with joining the third table into my query.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong here? For this example, 3 people are staying, check-in date is `21/05/12` and check-out date is `21/05/18`

```
SELECT * FROM room r
WHERE  r.capacity >= 3
AND    r.room_num NOT IN
       ( SELECT b.room_num FROM reservation b WHERE NOT (b.CHECKOUT_DATE <= 21/05/12 OR b.CHECKIN_DATE >= 21/05/18)) 
AND    ( SELECT c.room_num FROM reservation2 c WHERE NOT (c.CHECKOUT_DATE <= 21/05/12 OR c.CHECKIN_DATE >= 21/05/18) ) 
ORDER BY r.ROOM_NUM;
```

Comment: `21/05/12` is 0.35. `date '2021-05-12'` is a date :)

Comment: That last `and (select ...)` doesn't make sense. It looks like it was meant to start with `and r.room_num in ...`